# cronjob for centos/directadmin server?

Tags: linux, php, scripting, cron

i want to run a cron job on centos/directadmin server

i want to run this page every minute. how i must do it?
http://site.com/index.php?action=script

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to call the website and have it run the PHP; use CURL or WGET

crontab -e as any user

`* * * * * /path/to/wget http://site.com/index.php?action=script > /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

Run the command

```
crontab -e
```

While logged in as the user you want to run the command as.

Since you are using [DirectAdmin](http://www.directadmin.com/) you can also add your command in the user control panel.

[image: Crontab is in the advanced menu]

And then enter your crontab information:

[image: Add crontab details]

In the command field using your example, you would use:

```
/usr/bin/wget http://site.com/index.php?action=script
```

Clicking "Prevent email" will add >/dev/null 2>&1 to the end of the line to suppress the email sent upon successful or unsuccessful crontab run.